# Convert String to Integer ArrayList Java

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

So the string is like this:

```
String favs = "[36, 40, 16]"
```

How can I save these values to the arraylist:

```
List<Integer> favs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: You need to demonstrate that you took some effort to solve the problem. Once you do that the people here can help you..

Comment: Create the array list, split the String using a regex, then loop over the resulting array, parsing each index and adding them to the array list.

Comment: If you show us some code, to asure that you at least tried it. I promise you that an answer will come out in less than 10 mins!

Comment: I tried  a lot of different aproaches, including converting to json using gson, but i deleted all because they didnt worked out.

Comment: Show your effort and describe the specific problem you encountered rather than deleting it and asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String favs = "[36, 40, 16]";
String replace = favs.replace("[","");
String replace1 = replace.replace("]","");
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>    (Arrays.asList(replace1.split(",")));
List<Integer> favList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String fav:arrayList){
    favList.add(Integer.parseInt(fav.trim()));
}
```

Comment: You converted it to String list, I need Integer list.

Comment: well, I think the OP wanted the list converted to an integer list.

Comment: Good aproach, the " " (space) must be replaced too.

Comment: Perfect solution works like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    String favs = "[36, 40, 16]";
    String[] favs2 = favs.replaceAll("\\[|\\]| ", "").split(",");
    List<Integer> listI = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < favs2.length; i++) {
        listI.add(Integer.parseInt(favs2[i]));
    }

    listI.forEach(datint -> System.out.println("" + datint));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> favss = new ArrayList<>();
        String favs = "[36, 40, 16]";

        String[] arr=favs.replaceAll("\\[|\\]| ", "").split(",");
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

           favss.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[i]));
       }
        System.out.println(favss.toString());
```